# Should I worry about moisture in my inflatable sleeping pad?

Tags: camping

I use a Therm-a-Rest NeoAir sleeping pad.  This is not self inflating, so I have to breathe in to the sleeping pad to inflate it.

Are there any precautions for storing the bag to avoid gnarly bacteria / mold from growing inside the sleeping pad since I'm inflating it with such moist air?  Is it enough to just store it with the valve open?

Comment: Good quetsion.  I worry about this too.

Comment: I thought about building an adapter for use with my bike pump in case I needed it, since most of my backpacking is really bikepacking... 

http://www.crazyguyonabike.com/doc/page/?page_id=163597

Comment: Also, there's an adapter to make any airtite bag a pump. http://cascadedesigns.com/therm-a-rest/accessories/neoair-airtap-pump/product

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It's a good thought, but I have had one that I have inflated by mouth for over 10 years. I usually store it valve open partially inflated. I live in Arizona and the temp in the shed can get to over 150 degrees F some days so valve closed would cause the bubble to pop. It has never given me trouble.

I have heard that this is an issue from people who have never owned one before, and usually as a selling point for solid mattresses. But I have never heard it as an issue from someone who owned one.

Comment: Do you store it fully laid out?  I think if it were rolled tightly, it wouldn't much matter if the valve is open.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding that the only time inflating a pad by breath is bad is when it will be used in sub-zero conditions, as the moisture can freeze inside the mattress.